# TSQL: Identify Unicode column

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, unicode

**Foreword**: *I am doing maintenance on an "old" PHP / SQL Server 2012 system, the goal is to improve the overall performance*.

I realized immediately that the database has many "quirks" but I would follow a policy, and I decided to start correcting the types of the columns, in particular I noticed that the columns containing text are ALL nvarchar (max), actually being an application web some of these columns are correct, many do not.
I'm trying to write a script that will allow me to set "varchar" as a data type for columns that do not contain unicode text.

I have done several studies without result, the only solution I found is to do the inserts into a table with a varchar column and verify that does not go wrong .. there is a smarter solution?

Comment: in my opinion, don't start your target with datatypes, there are other approaches need to start instead of changing datatypes, the next link is suggested for beginning : https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2008.08.database.aspx

Comment: Changing `NVARCHAR` to `VARCHAR` will reduce the size but will not have big impact on performance. You might even get in deep troubles with special characters, which suddenly return as `???` Especially dealing with a *web application* you should keep interculture and languages in mind...

Comment: Yes, you are right, but doing an analysis of the machines we noticed that: The database has become huge; queries are really slow; some queries can freeze the sql server machine; ALL text fields are nvarchar. I understand that in many cases can be corrected, but I have seen many cases it is not absolutely. Obviously it is my intention to go check on indexes and query, but I would first have certainty of the correctness of the data types of the columns. Some tables have 60 million lines, I think that using unnecessarily nvarchar rather than varchar may affect the weight of the data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From my comment:

> Changing `NVARCHAR` to `VARCHAR` will reduce the size but will not
>   have big impact on performance. You might even get in deep troubles
>   with special characters, which suddenly return as ??? Especially
>   dealing with a web application you should keep interculture and
>   languages in mind...

Besides this comment here's a query you could use to get a lot of *meta-data*

```
SELECT c.DOMAIN_CATALOG
      ,c.TABLE_SCHEMA
      ,c.TABLE_NAME 
      ,c.COLUMN_NAME
      ,c.DATA_TYPE
      ,c.CHARACTER_MAXIMUM_LENGTH
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS AS c
WHERE c.DATA_TYPE IN ('varchar','nvarchar')
ORDER BY c.CHARACTER_MAXIMUM_LENGTH -- (-1 indicates "MAX")
```

In general: Check the *meta-data* you can retrieve via `INFORMATION_SCHEMA`.

### UPDATE

Your comment

> Some tables have 60 million lines, I think that using unnecessarily nvarchar rather than varchar may affect the weight of the data

Well, with such big tables the pure size (page-load, disc-io) matters. But other attempts (indexes, sub-optimal structure...) will have way deeper impact...

### UPDATE 2

You might check something like this:

```
DECLARE  @tbl TABLE(Some16Bit NVARCHAR(MAX),Some8Bit VARCHAR(MAX));
INSERT INTO @tbl(Some16Bit) VALUES(N'plain'),(N'Using russian: слов');

UPDATE @tbl SET Some8Bit=CAST(Some16Bit AS VARCHAR(MAX));

SELECT *
      ,CASE WHEN Some16Bit<>Some8Bit THEN 'Needs NVARCHAR' ELSE 'OK' END AS CheckNVARCHAR
FROM @tbl
```

The result

```
Some16Bit            Some8Bit           CheckNVARCHAR
-----------------------------------------------------
plain                plain              OK
Using russian: слов Using russian: ???? Needs NVARCHAR
```

Comment: I thank you but I'm looking for a script that allows me to identify the fields that contain unicode characters for whom it is really necessary to use nvarchar columns

Comment: Are you really trying to read tables with millions of rows, take **any `nvarchar` column**, split this **to any single character** and check for the need of unicode? Even if you detect columns which **might** be `8-bit` charset, this could break later... To be honest: I'd start somewhere else...

Comment: @user1576228 See my UPDATE 2